# Screen and audio cast for Google Glass app demo

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am working on my Glass app demo and I used [droidAtScreen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/) to project the screencast from MyGlass for the presentation. The problem is that I cannot demonstrate the voice responses from the Glass based on user input. My backup plan is to record a video for demonstration and insert the voice output manually. Does anyone know if there is a better way to do both screen and audio cast for Google Glass app demo? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem initially.

- Use **[Screencast-O-Matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/)** to record the video of screencast on my
  laptop. The screencast is done using **[DroidAtScreen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/)** with
  **highest frame rate possible** option checked. It has better frame rate than ASM screencast. During the video record session, my voice was captured. (so in other words, choose a
  quiet place!!)
- For simulating the Text-to-Speech engine voice, I used **[SitePal](http://www.oddcast.com/home/demos/tts/tts_example.php?sitepal)**
  demo site and the voice is Julie (US). It's the closest voice I could
  find that matches the Google Glass speech engine. To record the
  voice, I used **[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)** and export it to .wav audio file. The key
  is to play the video and find the exact time to insert the audio
  file using any standard movie maker software.

UPDATE

Just finished the demo presentation at IT Expo. To my surprise, the simplest solution worked the best.

- Create the video demo (under 2 minutes) as mentioned above but insist
  on asking an audience to try it out.
- Ask the person to say what
  he/she heard from the Glass app as a response to the action (ex. The
  item is saved)

Comment: Seems to me you could do one step better: connect a USB mic to the recording laptop and have it be close to the mono earbud for Glass.  This way it could pick up you talking and the response from Glass directly.  This question reminds me of this old but very professional video demonstrating Glass with audio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXlfxcqZheU

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely try it. One side note to this was that a diagram of the timeline cards and the workflow is a must. I received the feedback that even with a video demo, some people had difficulty follow along and understand the design.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Android Screen Monitor? I always use ASM.jar for any demonstration and it works fine with both audio and video demonstrations.

The link to download ASM.jar is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/downloads/list).

Detailed description is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/). If you're using Droid@Screen than probably you know how to run Android Screen Monitor (ASM.jar), but here is a [link](http://neatocode.tumblr.com/post/49566072064/mirroring-google-glass) for a reference that explains the process in detail.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I'll check it and let you know asap! :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I guess it is not what I am looking for. I need to capture the interaction between my Glass app and the user (voice interaction) for the demo. I can't find any application that can accomplish this task. Thanks again